# How do I create a days_in_year function using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I'm trying to create a simply column using Pandas that will calculate the number of days in the year of the adjacent date column.

I've already done this fairly easily for the numbers of days in the month using the daysinmonth attribute of DatetimeIndex, with the following:

```
def daysinmonth(row):
    x = pd.DatetimeIndex(row['Date']).daysinmonth
    return x  
daysinmonth(df)
```

I'm having trouble to mimic these results for year without the nifty pre-defined attribute.

my dataframe looks like the following (sans the days_in_year column since i'm trying to create that):

```
        Date       Days_in_month    Days_in_year
1       2/28/2018      28               365
2       4/14/2019      30               365
3       1/1/2020       31               366
4       2/15/2020      29               366
```

Thanks to anyone who takes a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the mode of year by 4 , equal to 0 means 366, else means 365(Notice this will not include the special cases , You can check the update function and the link I provided)

```
(pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.year%4).eq(0).map({True:366,False:365})
Out[642]: 
1    365
2    365
3    366
4    366
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

You can using this which is more accurate for decided leap year ,definition from this [site](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html)

```
def daysinyear(x):
    if x%4==0 :
       if x%100==0:

            if x%400==0:
                return(366)
            else:
                return (365)
       else :
           return(365)
    else:
        return(365)


(pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.year%4).apply(daysinyear)
Out[656]: 
1    365
2    365
3    366
4    366
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: this sounds like a great solution! I have one very beginner follow up question though: how should I think about you using df.Date?  I have never understood how a column name can be used as an attribute--what would happen if my column name was two words?

Comment: @Ben Then you need using df['Date something']

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `YearEnd`. You'll get a timedelta64 column with this method.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import YearEnd
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

(df.Date + YearEnd(1)) - (df.Date - YearEnd(1))

1   365 days
2   365 days
3   366 days
4   366 days
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using periods:

```
df['Date'].dt.to_period('A').dt.to_timestamp('A').dt.dayofyear
```

Output:

```
1    365
2    365
3    366
4    366
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this>

```
import datetime
    import numpy as np
    def func(date):
        year = date.year
        begin = datetime.datetime(year,1,1)
        end = datetime.datetime(year,12,31)
        diff = (end - begin)
        result = np.timedelta64(diff, "D").astype("int") 
        return  result
    print(func(datetime.datetime(2016,12,31)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to take the first day of one year and of the next year. Then calculate the difference. You can then apply this using `pd.Series.apply`:

```
def days_in_year(x):
    day1 = x.replace(day=1, month=1)
    day2 = day1.replace(year=day1.year+1)
    return (day2 - day1).days

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Days_in_year'] = df['Date'].apply(days_in_year)

print(df)

        Date  Days_in_month  Days_in_year
1 2018-02-28             28           365
2 2019-04-14             30           365
3 2020-01-01             31           366
4 2020-02-15             29           366
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basic formula to check if a year is a leap year and add the result to 365 to get the number of days in a year.

```
# Not needed if df ['Date'] is already of type datetime
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

years = dates.dt.year

ndays = 365 + ((years % 4 == 0) & ((years % 100 != 0) | (years % 400 == 0))).astype(int)
```